# Auto Mount NTFS Drive (on Ubuntu 18.04) to a Folder on Ubuntu Mate (Rpi4, Ubuntu Server 19.10)

Tags: ntfs, ubuntu-mate, automount, raspberrypi

First timer here and a Ubuntu noob, hope I can break down my question clearly. So currently have 2 setups:

1. PC with Ubuntu 18.04, with 2 NTFS drives mounted back when I was using Windows
2. Raspberry pi 4. Installed Ubuntu Mate through Ubuntu server 19.10

To mount the NTFS folder on my PC, I used the following:

- edit /etc/fstab
- UUID=XXXXXX /media/windows/drive ntfs-3g fmask=000,dmask=000,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0

I then proceeded to go to the mounted folder, right click, and use the 'Local Network Share' and enable Guest Access for simplicity.

Next, I went to my rpi4 and tried to access the folder via file manager. It opened just fine. When I dragged the directory to terminal, the path is something like this:
smb://drelocallinux/._media

Now, I'm at lost in how I can auto-mount this onto my local folder in Rpi4. My goal is to eventually map this folder to a docker container, but that's later down the road.

Please advise, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for sending me that link. I didn't try that but I did try this this morning and it worked for me

//192.168.0.193/foreign /media/windows/foreign_media cifs uid=1000,gid=1000,user,noexec,credentials=/etc/samba/cifspassword 0 0

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

//192.168.0.193/foreign /media/windows/foreign_media cifs uid=1000,gid=1000,user,noexec,credentials=/etc/samba/cifspassword 0 0